# Loopback array of numbers returned as String

Tags: json, node.js, rest, loopbackjs

I'm just getting started with Loopback.

I have a model with a property that needs to be an array of numbers:

```
"numbers": {
  type: [
    "number"
  ]
},
```

I believe I've defined it correctly - [this](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/LoopBack+types#LoopBacktypes-Arraytypes) is what I'm following.

When I use the REST api to get the object, the "number" property is returned as a string:

```
"numbers": "[6,3]",
```

I expect it to return as:

```
"numbers": [6,3],
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `JSON.parse(number)` should help you.